# Exporting large data with H5 format cuase crash

Tags: export

When I export a list of 49000 matrices which are 100by100 I get some errors.

```
Export["data.h5", data];
```

Returns:

```
LinkObject::linkw: Unable to write data to closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\HDF5.exe",77553,10]. >>
```

In the document it is written that:

```
This message is generated by an attempt to write to a MathLink connection that is not active.
```

The size of `data` is at minimum 3.5 GB. I need to export in `H5`format because it's fast.
Any idea how I can overcome this issue?

To reproduce the problem:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]

a = Flatten[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}], {i, 1, 49}, {j, 1, 1000}], 1];

Export["a.h5", a]
```

Comment: Perhaps you do not have enough disk space?

Comment: I have 700GB disk space on the location I want to save the data.

Comment: I tried to save a (simple) random matrix of 100 by 100, which was ok.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I put the code which produces the same error on my PC. Could you please try it?

Comment: It took a while, but it did save the file, which was 3738 MB.

Comment: I tried that in MMA 10.0.2 (Linux). I have also tried to  use `ParallelTable`, also works.

Comment: Theoretical size of the raw data is 3738.4 MiB. So I think the storage is being done efficiently, if not quickly.

Comment: if you just need to save the data for later import to  mathematica use "mx" format.

Comment: @george2079 Did you reproduce the error?

Comment: no, just offering an alternative approach in case you cant sort it out.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Is there an another way to save the data which is as fast as `.h5` format? `wdx` is really slow.

Comment: @yashar sorry, I don't know. In version 10, the MX format is less platform-specific than it was previously, and this will be fast. As for the speed of the other import/export converters, you would have to test these for yourself. I get the impression that most of them are not very optimized.

Answer (score 1):

There are some serious issues with the way mathematica implements the hdf5 standard; it is only a small subset. Specifically, data is saved as an attribute (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/13_Attributes.html) which leads to some pretty strong restrictions as to what one can do, "We generally consider the maximum size of an attribute to be 64K bytes. The library has two ways of storing attributes larger than 64K bytes: in dense attribute storage or in a separate dataset. Using dense attribute storage is described in this section, and storing in a separate dataset is described in the next section."
I found out the hard way that this is the case storing only small data sets...

Comment: While I think you are correct about Mathematica only implementing a small subset of hdf5 (and even that subsets lacks in quality), I think it is not correct that "data is saved as an attribute". If I check a file generated with Mathematica (with a dataset definitely violating the attribute restrictions) e.g. HDFView I see the exported dataset  reported as type "HDF5 Scalar Dataset". Can you explain why you think "data is saved as an attribute"?

Answer (score 0):

You can see:

https://github.com/scotmartin1234/HDF5Mathematica

I am not sure if it will crash as you noted in your own post, but it is a completely separate approach that the built-in HDF5, so you might be in luck.

This is version 2.00 (August 2016) of the package that was originally provided as version 1.00 in July 2011.

Comment: does this work for mac? I had a look and it seems that it doesnt